# Getting nested array from JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

[This](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=e710784749a34cd2a41260bc92a7dcd2) is my JSON.
Stored in variable named `$onceBooking`.

I want to get `booking_slots` from each `booking`.

This is my code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($onceBooking); $i++) {
    if (count($onceBooking[$i]->bookings) == 0) {
        $onceBooking[$i]->total_days = 0;
    } else {
        $onceBooking[$i]->total_days = count($onceBooking[$i]->bookings);
        $bookings = $onceBooking[$i]->bookings;
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($bookings); $j++) {
            return $bookings[$j]->booking_slots;
        }
    }
}
```

But it's returning nothing. Please tell me if I am wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you decoded the JSON response in your $onceBooking array ? If not, use `$onceBooking = json_decode($onceBooking, true);` and then check the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify the code a little bit because you are returning the first element's booking slot.

```
$data = json_decode($onceBooking);
$bookingSlots = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($onceBooking); $i++) {
    if (count($onceBooking[$i]->bookings) == 0) {
        $onceBooking[$i]->total_days = 0;
    } else {
        $onceBooking[$i]->total_days = count($onceBooking[$i]->bookings);
        $bookings = $onceBooking[$i]->bookings;
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($bookings); $j++) {
            if (!empty($bookings[$j])) {
                $bookingSlots[$bookings[$j]->id] = $bookings[$j]->booking_slots;
            }
        }
    }
}
return $bookingSlots;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok. Glad I could help.

Comment: that is because `true` keyword is used in json_decode function to convert the response as Associative Arrays. As in your code, you are accessing the Objects that is created if true is not used. If true is used then you'll have to access them in array format.

Comment: Sure. No Problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = json_decode($onceBooking);
```

Then you can loop through data to grab your booking objects.

```
$result = ["total_days" => 0];

foreach($data as $instance) {
    $result["total_days"] += count($instance->bookings);
    $bookings = $instance->bookings;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($bookings); $i++) {
        return $bookings->booking_slots;
    }
}
```

-- EDIT: for returning total days & bookings.

```
$result = ["total_days" => 0, "bookings" => []];

foreach($data as $instance) {
    $result["total_days"] += count($instance->bookings);
    array_push($result["bookings"], $instance->$bookings);
}

return $result;
```

Comment: the return statement seems odd, feel like you're not even using the total_days variable then.

Comment: Actually, i want to calculate total days of booking that's why i am using total _days.

Comment: if bookings contains no slots then add total_days as 0 otherwise get the slots and count there unique days.

Comment: Added an edit to return the bookings for you to calculate in your calling method.

Comment: thanks but i want to count unique booking_slots as total_days if booking is not null